# How do I configure Opera to be able to use the built-in VPN and Super User's website?

Tags: discussion

Visiting Super User from Google when searching for a question shows a *page not found*.

I kept thinking that the Super User deleted information so I used web-archive to find pages. But then once I turned off my VPN and noticed that Super User loaded nicely:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/a2001daed947b35db3f0fa71cb497888.png]

As you can see on the above image, it doesn't let me visit with Opera's built-in VPN. But turning it off, it loads correctly. Is there some .cfg I can use to either:

A: Turn off VPN for website http://*.superuser.com/

B: Some script bypass, catch the IP address before leaking quickly turn off VPN, download website to cache (memory, and then turn on VPN and load the website). I dunno, something crazy I am willing to try.

Comment: I am going to vote to move this to meta.superuser, as I suspect the SE developers, would consider this just to be a bug.

Comment: What version of Opera?

Comment: VERSION 41.0 - i feel like this is for all of them regardless. I thought superuser.com was doing the blocking of the VPN since this is the only website that does this.

Comment: I just tried on VERSION 42.0 same problem.

Comment: after admin migrated my post to meta.superuser.com i was able to open it up there flawlessly while using the vpn. This is not a Opera issue. This is a superuser.com issue.

Comment: An administrator didn't move your question the community did

Comment: I have the same problem. Definitely a superuser.com problem.